# Conveying "to be in someone's good books"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

The [idiom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-in-sb-s-good-bad-books) "to be in someone's good books" means (informally) to be in a state in which one is liked or are treated nicely by someone. For example:

> He's trying to get back in his boss's good books by offering to work overtime.

How can one convey this in French? I think that

> Il essaie de revenir dans les bonnes grâces de son patron en proposant de faire des heures supplémentaires.

sounds a little formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your proposal might be the best that conveys the idea of convincing someone to be nice to you without being manipulative. In my personal experience (native French, 25y/o, educated middle-class background), this expression can be understood by almost anyone and does not sound formal as it is an expression.

Something that might sound a bit too shady is ***[être dans les petits papiers [de qqun]](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/etre-dans-les-petits-papiers-de-quelqu-un)***. This sounds a bit like the boss would give unfair favors to the employee because of that.

> Il essaie d'**être dans les petits papiers** de son patron en proposant de faire des heures supplémentaires.

Another expression that came to my mind is ***[mettre [qqun] dans sa poche](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mettre_dans_sa_poche)***.

> Il essaie de **mettre son patron dans sa poche** en proposant de faire des heures supplémentaires.

or

> Il essaie de **se mettre son patron dans la poche** en proposant de faire des heures supplémentaires.

However, in this context, I'm not sure it's appropriate as it involves a form of manipulation, or maybe even superiority, over the person you are trying to convince.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for something like :

> Il **cherche à attirer les faveurs** de son patron en proposant de faire des heures supplémentaires.